# Event to detect drag in angular 2

Tags: ionic3, ng2-dragula

I have a screen where I'm rearranging card with the help of ng2-dragula. The cards are get dragged and dropped but I want to know the event during which I can update certain data.[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Dragula has an API of events that return a Drake object, which contains many different pieces of data, depending on how you've structured your Dragula binding.
Here is the API documentation with a listing: https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#drakeon-events
There is a specific 'drop' event, if that's what you're asking for.
Your question isn't very specific, so I cannot offer more than that without more clarification.